# How to store API-secrets in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, security

Is there a way to store a secret key (e.g. API key) in flutter?

Use-case:
When registering a new user on my app I need to talk to my backend. Since I only want devices that I know to register users, this backend has only authenticated endpoints. Which means I need to have an API key to authorize the app.

I know you can store environment variables or configurations inside config file or user secrets in a encrypted database but there are a some problems with that in this case:

- config file can be recovered with all of its content by just unzipping the apk file which means there are no real secrets there...
- To have a secret in a database, you need to put it there first which is not possible before runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably use environnement variable, and also, I'll obfuscate my Dart code.
There is multiple tutorials, but i'll send you the one from the documentation:
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate

Comment: Thanks but this does not take away the fact that when the apk is unzipped, the secrets are just there in plain text. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you really don't want to have any trace of you API secret on your APK, you have to create a route on your backend to get the API secret through this route.

Comment: Thought of that as well, but if the secret is on a backend, either it is available for everyone or I won't be able to get it :)